# Laravel changed my table name unexpectedly?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make many-to-many db relationships in my website, to let "Student" have both "Universities" and "Majors" as many-to-many:

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';
    protected $fillable = ['username','password','email','degree','avatar','description'];

    public function universities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\University');
    }

    public function majors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Major');
    }
}
```

And I also created models and migration files, both `create_student_university_table.php`
and `create_student_major_table.php`.

But when creating new student, a terribly strange error occured:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ozudb.major_student' doesn't exist

It's so weird for two aspects:

1. The `University` thing works perfectly, but it won't work for `Major` even they are exactly the same process
2. I never typed any thing like `major_student`! The migration file generates `student_major` table. I even searched for keywords `major_student` and find no result in all my files.

This weird question has ruined my evening - still struggling.
And here's what happens when creating a new student:

```
public function postStudentRegister(Request $request)
    {
        \Auth::login("student",$this->createStudent($request->all()));

        // store student_university and student_major pairs into table
        $student = Student::where('username',$request->username)->first();
        $uniarr = [];
        $majorarr = [];

        $arr = explode(',', $request->universities);
        $arrLen = sizeof($arr);
        for($i=0;$i<$arrLen;$i++) {
            array_push($uniarr, University::where('name',$arr[$i])->first()->id);
        };
        $student->universities()->attach($uniarr);

        $arr = explode(',', $request->majors);
        $arrLen = sizeof($arr);
        for($i=0;$i<$arrLen;$i++) {
            array_push($majorarr, Major::where('name',$arr[$i])->first()->id);
        };
        $student->majors()->attach($majorarr);

        return redirect('student/regis-success');

    }
```

The error is intrigued by the last second line, `$student->majors()->attach($majorarr);`

Laravel please, why you change my table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why laravel is looking for major_students instead of student_major is that when laravel is dynamically querying for a many to many relationship it picks the two Model that is Student and Major and check which one's first letter alphabetically comes first so in this case M that is major comes first. It will join the two models (ie. with an underscore) that is Major and student(as i said "M" comes first) and lowercase them as major_student.

So that is why you are seeing that error.

To force laravel to use your own custom table name you can pass a second argument to your belongsToMany function like this

```
public function universities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\University','student_major');
}

public function majors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Major', 'student_major');
}
```

And moreover this is a bonus to your question.

Am foreseeing N + 1 query problems with your code in your controller. The foreach and the where clause will cause several calls to your database which is not efficient.

```
 public function postStudentRegister(Request $request)
{
    \Auth::login("student",$this->createStudent($request->all()));

    // store student_university and student_major pairs into table
    $student = Student::where('username',$request->username)->first();
    $uniarr = [];
    $majorarr = [];

    $arr = explode(',', $request->universities);
    $arrLen = sizeof($arr);
    for($i=0;$i<$arrLen;$i++) {
        array_push($uniarr, $arr[$i]);
    };

    // This will get all the ids of the universities with names in the $uniarr thereby preventing several calls to the database;
    $uniIdList = University::whereIn('name',$uniarr)->lists('id')->all()
    $student->universities()->attach($uniIdList);

    $arr = explode(',', $request->majors);
    $arrLen = sizeof($arr);
    for($i=0;$i<$arrLen;$i++) {
        array_push($majorarr, $arr[$i]);
    };

    // This will get all the ids of the Major's with names in the $uniarr thereby preventing several calls to the database;
    $majorIdList = Major::whereIn('name',$majorarr)->lists('id')->all();
    $student->majors()->attach($majorIdList);

    return redirect('student/regis-success');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pivot tables for `many-to-many` relations. Eloquent is looking for `major_student`, which is a pivot table which has two foreign keys: `major_id` and `student_id`. You need to create migration and execute it.

You're saying that you do not use `major_student` words anywhere, but the thing is Eloquent uses the table automatically. For example this code trying to use it:

```
$student->majors()->attach($majorarr);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

To force Laravel to use custom named pivot tables you can use second parameter:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Major', 'student_major');
```

Comment: Thanks, you are leading me to the right direction! But the table name that Eloquent is using seems totally random. 
Shall I just delete the migrattion "create_student_major_table.php", and make a new migration "create_major_student_table.php"?

Comment: Try to rollback, change table name to `major_student` and migrate again. Also, can you post your migrations please? Also, you can force Laravel to use custom named pivot.